# The use of the words "encountered, identified, existing" together with the word "type"

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following verbs is correct in the phrase:

> the three types of children **encountered/identified/existing** in French society?

Comment: I would choose 'encountered.' That is only my opinion. 'Identified' sounds awkward; but euphony is not a topic that is encouraged on this site.

Comment: Hi Alina, before we can answer the question, we need to know something: What do you want to communicate? Also, is this a homework question? [If so, we have certain requirements for those.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**identified** is a better choice.
'encountered' is used when there is an element of 'unexpectedness'. Since the above statement does not reveal something unexpected or sudden, encountered is not an apt choice.
When you use 'existing' you associate a natural or innate truth with it. The fact that 3 types of children have been identified is not an innate truth which was always true and has been rediscovered or proven. This sounds like an outcome of a survey/ research and is open to interpretations.
 Another survey may say there are 5 types based on how they divide the groups. So, 3 and 5 cannot exist together in this case, while 3 and 5 can be identified together.